# accessing method of a plugin from gsp

Tags: grails

I have a plugin with a namespace. I am trying to access the method of the plugin through the namespace using the following in the GSP which is not recognizing the namespace at all.

Thanks,
Pooja

Comment: provide a minimal code example and what you tried

Comment: give your code for better understanding